# Spring Security - need 403 error, not redirect

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.0.4. I have a bunch of web service which are protected by Spring Security. When I access them as an unauthenticated user, Spring Security redirects to login page. Instead of that, I want to return HTTP 403 error. How can I achieve that?

Here is my security config:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" >

    <intercept-url pattern="/authorization.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/registration.jsp" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/authorization/auth" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/authorization/new" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/accounts/new" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/extjs/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <form-login login-page="/authorization.jsp"
            default-target-url="/index.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/registration.jsp?login_error=1"
            always-use-default-target="true"
            />

    <logout logout-success-url="/authorization.jsp"
            logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            invalidate-session="true"/>        

</http>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the "authentication-failure-url" setting on your form login?

Comment: Have you found working solution? I've heard that the way to achieve that is to override 'some Spring filters', but without example, and I think it should be possible to configure because e.g. AJAX application like to do custom loging on JSON channel and JSON channels for data are expected to react with 403 on no rights to service.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339431/how-to-handle-expired-session-using-spring-security-and-jquery

Answer (score 17):

For java configuration you need to do

```
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(alwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint);
```

Where alwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint is innstance of class

```
public class AlwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public final void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                               AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

This disables default behavior of Spring (redirecting unauthenticated requests to login form).

Side note:
for such case HTTP code *SC_UNAUTHORIZED(401)* is better choice than *SC_FORBIDDEN(403)*.

Comment: Not sure the exact version where this was added, but there is also `http.exceptionHandling(Customizer<ExceptionHandlingConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>)`, so you can customize the default. For example: `http.exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))`. HttpStatusEntryPoint is also convenient as you don't need to create your own implementation of AuthenticationEntrypPoint.

Comment: If you don't want it to always return a particular status code, you can also call the customer and add a default entry point, which takes a matcher. If the matcher matches the request, it'll use this entry point. Ex: `customizer.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED), matcher)`, where the matcher is any RequestMatcher implementation. There's many out of the box RequestMatcher's so it's a pretty flexible option.

Answer (score 10):

There's an article on the spring forums [here](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-101102.html) that outlines how to get your app determining between the two methods. So far I'm using the following code to secure my data controllers:

```
<bean id="ep403" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>

<sec:http pattern="/data/**" entry-point-ref="ep403" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
</sec:http>

<bean id="epauth" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/login.html"/>
</bean>

<sec:http pattern="/**" entry-point-ref="epauth" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
</sec:http>
```

So the whole DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint solution in the article I linked is a bit more heavyweight, but I imagine it does the job just fine as well.

Comment: The solution in the article you posted solved this problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: The link given above (linking to Legacy Spring Forums) has shut down since February 28, 2019. Any alternative links?

Answer (score 10):

you need to

- Create a `RequestMatcher` to determine which requests should get a 403 (`AntPathRequestMatcher` may suffice in your case).
- Configure the `HttpSessionRequestCache` to check the matcher and not store those pages for post-login redirect.
- Use a `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint` to either 403 the request outright or redirect to login according to the matcher.

See the example here:

http://distigme.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/ajax-and-spring-security-form-based-login/

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me ([reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9548))

```
http
  ...
  .oauth2Login().permitAll()
  .and().exceptionHandling()
  .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
       new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED),
       new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"))
            ...
```

Answer (score -4):

It should return a 403 error unless you configure it to go to another url with this tag:

```
<sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/urlToGoIfForbidden" />
```

Comment: Yes, asker knows it should, because he asked this question. And he asked becuse it does not.

Comment: This tag works only for AUTHENITCATED users with not enough PREVILAGES (what stands in the docs..)