# Spring Boot Security 403 redirect

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot, ldap

I'm using Spring Boot Security to authenticate users with LDAP for an app. By default, this configuration redirects unauthorized users to the login page. I would like to tweak this configuration to achieve two things:

1. Redirect unauthenticated users trying to access the single page application (at "/") to login. This already works with default behavior.
2. For api calls ("/api/v1/..."), I want to return a 403 error message instead of redirecting.

How would I do this? I've seen some other questions that have given me hints but I still haven't been able to figure it out.

The top answer on this post seems relevant, but he links to an XML-method of doing this. I want to do it with Java.
[Spring Security - need 403 error, not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269686/spring-security-need-403-error-not-redirect)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my current setup:

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that seems to work (so far, least)

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingEntryPoint() {
    final LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint> map = new LinkedHashMap();
    map.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"), new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));
    map.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api_v1/**"), new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());

    final DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(map);
    entryPoint.setDefaultEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));

    return entryPoint;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //delegates based on url (api vs root)
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingEntryPoint());

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone down the road.  I know it took me a long time to find answer. :)

Comment: I think instead of using Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint, using HttpStatusEntryPoint along with a 401 (unauthorized) status code is a better choice here.

Comment: That initial entry into the LinkedHashMap (the one tied to "/") may not be necessary as the default entry point would handle it anyway.